# mailcore2 via SMTP Outlook.com gives Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established."

Tags: ios, objective-c, smtp, mailcore2, outlook.com

I am setting up outlook.com with mailcore2 on iOS9 in Objective-C.  I have gmail working already with both imap and smtp.  I can fetch emails fine from outlook.com but when I try and send an email I get the following error:

> Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server
>   could not be established."

Below is a sample of my code:

```
MCOSMTPSession *session = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
[session setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2Outlook];
[session setOAuth2Token:accessToken];
[session setUsername:@"user@outlook.com"];
[session setHostname:@"smtp-mail.outlook.com"];
[session setPort:25];  //also tried 587
[session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS];  //Also tried MCOConnectionTypeTLS and MCOConnectionTypeClear
[session setCheckCertificateEnabled:false];

MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation = [session sendOperationWithData:data];
[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
}];
```

I also tried the `checkAccountOperationWithFrom` operation but that also gave the same error.

Comment: where did you get the server address smtp-mail.outlook.com?

Comment: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/resources/providers.json and http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com/f/What-Are-The-Outlook-com-Smtp-Server-Settings.htm

Comment: 587 seems to work for me.

Comment: just a question: how did you get gmail to work? normal smtp or oauth2 or 'less secure apps'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I used MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to fetch emails from Outlook, can you tell me what are the changes to be done in my Imap Settings.Below is the code i am using..

```
session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc]init];
session.hostname = @"imap-mail.outlook.com";
session.username = @"dummy@outlook.com";
session.password = nil;
session.port = 993;
session.OAuth2Token = accessToken;
session.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS;
session.authType = MCOAuthTypeSASLLogin;
session.checkCertificateEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, iOS 13, Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)**

```
Also Need to Disable Captcha :  [https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha][1]
```

> Response: Successfully sent email!

Here is the perfect solution:

```
    @IBAction func btnSendMailClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print(#function)
    let smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
    smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpSession.username = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
    smtpSession.password = "password" //You can create [App Password from gmail setting][1] 

    smtpSession.port = 587 //25
    smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.saslPlain
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.startTLS
    smtpSession.isCheckCertificateEnabled = false

    smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
        if data != nil {
            if let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
            }
        }
    }

    let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
    builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Swifty Developers", mailbox: "swiftydevelopers@gmail.com")!]
    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Mehul Parmar", mailbox: "mehulasjack@gmail.com")
    builder.header.subject = "My message"
    builder.htmlBody = "Yo Rool, this is a test message!"

    let rfc822Data = builder.data()
    let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperation(with: rfc822Data)
    sendOperation?.start { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error sending email: \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            NSLog("Successfully sent email!")
        }
    }
}
```